# How to get linestring length while drawing?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

I've got a control to draw lines:

```
new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vecLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
            callbacks : {
            //    "done" : doneHandler,
                "point" : function(aPoint){
                    console.log(aPoint);
                }
            }
        })
```

and now i can get all points from linestring i add to the map. But what i need is to get length of the feature that is not finished (the reason i can't use `done` callback).

How can i make this? I'm completly stuck, any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achive this with immediate measures and [OpenLayers Measure Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/measure.html) will help you about your que. Dont forget to check measure distance and use immediate measures...

i hope it helps you

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to **Aragon**, i've made it this way:

```
        var measure_ctrl = new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
        persist : true,
        immediate : true,
        handlerOptions : {
            layer : vecLayer
        }
    });
        measure_ctrl.events.on({
        "measure" : handleFinalMeasurements,
        "measurepartial" : handleMeasurements
    });
```

and then getting `event.measure`